# How do i select one image from a result list of images?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an images table for posts. Each post may have multiple images. I just want to fetch one of the images for any post.

Here's what i want to achieve using vanilla PHP on MySQL:

```
SELECT disk_image_filename FROM Vehiclepostimages WHERE (vehicleposts_id = ' . $id . ') ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

But i can't get it to work in Laravel. Here's my code in Laravel:

```
$image = Vehiclepostimages ::where([ 
            ['Vehicleposts_id', '=', $id],
        ])->value('disk_image_filename')->orderBy('id ASC')->get();
```

Comment: if you call an image out side of loop it will give you one of that images, or limit 1

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for `orderBy` is incorrect.

```
$image = Vehiclepostimages::where('Vehicleposts_id', $id)
              ->value('disk_image_filename')
              // Takes two parameters. Default for 2nd is 'ASC'
              ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
              ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Value retrieves the first record, you don't need to use get() also.

```
$image = Vehiclepostimages::where('Vehicleposts_id', $id)
              ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
              ->value('disk_image_filename');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. This is what finally worked:

```
/** Logic for getting a vehicle's top or first image data from the image table */
public function topImage($id)
{
    $image = Vehiclepostimages ::where('Vehicleposts_id', $id)
          ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();

    return $image;
}
```